# How to add special character at the beginning and end of a line in a text file using a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add " (inverted comma) at the beginning and end of a line in multiple text files so that when I convert these .txt files into .csv files the entire string array is available in 1st cell and not comma-separated. I have data in the text file with the comma (,) in it and I don't want the string to be delimited by commas.

I am able to add " at the end of the line but unable to put at the beginning.

```
$files = "F:\processed\*.txt"
Add-Content $files`" | Set-Content $file.PSPath -Force
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you don't need to do that. If you want to turn a plain text file into a csv file you can do it like this:

```
Get-Content -Path D:\sample\test.txt |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Vaule = $_
        }
    } |
    Export-Csv -Path D:\sample\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Or ...

```
Get-Content -Path D:\sample\empty\test.txt |
    Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'Value'; Expression = {$_}} |
        Export-Csv -Path D:\sample\empty\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

would do the same ... ;-)

Here's how to convert the files in bulk:

```
$Path = 'F:\processed'
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *.txt |
    ForEach-Object {
        $OutputFile = Join-Path -Path $_.Directory -ChildPath ($_.BaseName + '.csv')
        Get-Content -Path $_.FullName |
            ForEach-Object {
                $_ -replace '^(.+)$', '"$1"'
            } |
                Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile
    }
```

Comment: Hi Olaf, Thanks for the suggestion. this converts the text file into CSV but it is also generating header as "Value" that I do not need. Plus I need to do this for multiple text files in a directory. so I have modified the path as 
Get-Content -Path F:\processed\*.txt  
but this did not work

Comment: You could have mentioned that in your question. A csv file with only one column and without header is actually not a csv file. Every tool able to work with standard conform csv files shouldn't have a problem with the header. Anyway I added another example how you could do.